# Reading a file -- pairing a String and int value -- with multiple split lines

Tags: java, string, file, stringtokenizer

I am working on an exercise with the following criteria:

**"The input consists of pairs of tokens where each pair begins with the type of ticket that the person bought ("coach", "firstclass", or "discount", case-sensitively) and is followed by the number of miles of the flight.**"

The list can be paired -- `coach 1500   firstclass 2000   discount 900   coach 3500` -- and this currently works great. However, when the String and int value are split like so:

```
firstclass        5000  coach         1500         coach
100 firstclass

2000    discount 300
```

it breaks entirely. I am almost certain that it has something to do with me using this format (not full)

```
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(fileScanner.nextLine(), " ")
    while(token.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String ticketClass = token.nextToken().toLowerCase();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
        ...
    }
}
```

because it will always read the first value as a String and the second value as an integer. I am very lost on how to keep track of one or the other while going to read the next line. Any help is truly appreciated.

Similar (I think) problems:

- [Efficient reading/writing of key/value pairs to file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202923/efficient-reading-writing-of-key-value-pairs-to-file-in-java#13202961)
- [Java-Read pairs of large numbers from file and represent them with linked list, get the sum and product of each pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396842/java-read-pairs-of-large-numbers-from-file-and-represent-them-with-linked-list)
- [Reading multiple values in multiple lines from file (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530897/reading-multiple-values-in-multiple-lines-from-file-java)

Comment: The Javadoc for `StringTokenizer` says _"...StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. ..."_ and I don't think you need it.  You should be able to get by, just by calling `hasNext()`, `next()` and `nextInt()` on your `Scanner`.  No need even for `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford to read the text file in all at once as a very long `String`, simply use the built-in [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) with the regex `\\s+`, like so

```
String[] tokens = fileAsString.split("\\s+");
```

This will split the input file into tokens, assuming the tokens are separated by one or more [whitespace](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) characters (a whitespace character covers newline, space, tab, and carriage return). Even and odd tokens are ticket types and mile counts, respectively.

If you absolutely have to read in line-by-line and use `StringTokenizer`, a solution is to count number of tokens in the last line. If this number is odd, the first token in the current line would be of a different type of the first token in the last line. Once knowing the starting type of the current line, simply alternating types from there.

```
int tokenCount = 0;
boolean startingType = true; // true for String, false for integer
boolean currentType;
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(fileScanner.nextLine(), " ");
    startingType = startingType ^ (tokenCount % 2 == 1); // if tokenCount is odd, the XOR ^ operator will flip the starting type of this line
    tokenCount = 0;
    while(token.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        tokenCount++;
        currentType = startingType ^ (tokenCount % 2 == 0); // alternating between types in current line
        if (currentType) {
            String ticketClass = token.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            // do something with ticketClass here
        } else {
            int mileCount = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            // do something with mileCount here
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never used `.split()` before. Does `\s+` translate to "any size string" or something to that effect?

Comment: No, `\s+` is a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) i.e., a search pattern. `\s` means a whitespace character and `+` means one or more of whatever comes before it. Overall `\s+` means one or more whitespace characters. The `split()` method then uses this regex as a delimiter for separating the tokens in the string.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't realize I could click on that at first, though I think I got it now. Thank you for that explanation and bookmark ;)

Answer (score 0):

**I found another way to do this problem without using either the StringTokenizer or the regex**...admittedly I had trouble with the regular expressions haha.

I declare these outside of the try-catch block because I want to use them in both my finally statement and return the points:

```
int points = 0;
ArrayList<String> classNames = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> classTickets = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then inside my try-statement, I declare the `index` variable because I won't need that outside of this block. That variable increases each time a new element is read. Odd elements are read as ticket classes and even elements are read as ticket prices:

```
try
{
    int index = 0;
    // read till the file is empty
    while(fileScanner.hasNext())
    {
        // first entry is the ticket type
        if(index % 2 == 0)
            classNames.add(fileScanner.next());
        // second entry is the number of points
        else
            classTickets.add(Integer.parseInt(fileScanner.next()));
        index++;
    }
}
```

You can either catch it here like this or use `throws NoSuchElementException` in your method declaration -- **As long as you catch it on your method call**

```
catch(NoSuchElementException noElement)
{
    System.out.println("<###-NoSuchElementException-###>");
}
```

Then down here, loop through the number of elements. See which flight class it is and multiply the ticket count respectively and return the points outside of the block:

```
finally
{
    for(int i = 0; i < classNames.size(); i++)
    {
        switch(classNames.get(i).toLowerCase())
        {
            case "firstclass":    // 2 points for first
                points += 2 * classTickets.get(i);
                break;
            case "coach":         // 1 point for coach
                points += classTickets.get(i);
                break;
            default:
                // budget gets nothing
        }
    }
}
return points;
```

The regex seems like the most convenient way, but this was more intuitive to me for some reason. Either way, I hope the variety will help out.

Comment: This works too, but may slow down your code because if an exception happens (which can be quite frequent in your example string), the [performance cost to create the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343209/which-part-of-throwing-an-exception-is-expensive) can be significant. In general, I think it's best to use exception to handle rare cases, not frequent ones.

Comment: Where would be the optimal place to test for/ throw exceptions in this case? Would it be in the method declaration and then up the stack to wherever that was called? I read that -- and a couple of other threads -- and am still not certain. This was another one that I read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164613/why-are-try-blocks-expensive

Comment: I don't think *throwing* already instantiated exceptions costs much in your code, but *instantiating* them does, as exceptions capture the stack trace at instantiation point. You can read more at the [article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/) linked at the end of the accepted answer of the linked question (specifically, the Lil' Exception is *Born* and Lil' Exception is *Thrown* sections).

Answer (score 0):

> simply use the built-in String.split() - @bui

I was finally able to wrap my head around regular expressions, but **\s+** was not being recognized for some reason. It kept giving me this error message:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  "  '  \ )Java(1610612990)

So when I went through with those characters instead, I was able to write this:

```
int points = 0, multiplier = 0, tracker = 0;
while(fileScanner.hasNext())
{
    String read = fileScanner.next().split(
            "[\b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ]")[0];
    if(tracker % 2 == 0)
    {
        if(read.toLowerCase().equals("firstclass"))
            multiplier = 2;
        else if(read.toLowerCase().equals("coach"))
            multiplier = 1;
        else
            multiplier = 0;
    }else
    {
        points += multiplier * Integer.parseInt(read);
    }
    tracker++;
}
```

This code goes one entry at a time instead of reading a whole array void of whitespace as a work-around for that error message I was getting. If you could show me what the code would look like with `String[] tokens = fileAsString.split("\s+");` instead I would really appreciate it :)

> you need to add another "\" before "\s" to escape the slash before "s" itself – @bui

Comment: My bad, I forgot that you need to add another "\" before "\s" to escape the slash before "s" itself. I edited my answer.

Comment: I wish I could double upvote it haha. Thank you for helping me understand how to use the regular expressions...if only my professor did that ;p